# Receiving Response from Serial Device in Arduino MEGA

Tags: arduino, gsm, gprs, sim900

I am a newbie with Arduino Mega 2560 .I have been trying to connect the Arduino and SIM900A  module(GSM/GPRS module).I have connected the USB to my PC(Serial instance) and pins 18(Tx) and 19(Rx) to Rx and Tx in the GSM/GPRS module respectively and the GND pin(GSM/GPRS) module's is connected to GND,one near pin 13 in the Arduino.

**Power connection:-**

I am powering using 12V supplies for each of the boards.

The below is my code.

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial1.begin(9600);
 delay(1000);
 Serial.print("Initial Setup !!");
 delay(5000); 
}


void loop()
{
if(Serial.available())
{
  char a=Serial.read();
  Serial1.print(a);
  //Serial.print(a);
}
if(Serial1.available())
{
  char B=Serial1.read();
  Serial.print(B);
  //Serial.print(a);
}
}
```

I am able to get the initial response in the "Serial Monitor" like (+CFUN:1,+CPIN:READY)(Once I open the Serial monitor I used to press the reset in the GSM/GPRSmodule).

But when I type some AT commands in the Serial Monitor,I am not able to get the response like "OK" from the GPRS/GSM Module.

Please let me know what I should be doing for getting the responses back from GSM/GPRS module.

Comment: When the modem is reset do you reconnect the serial connection?

Comment: Hi aldridmc..When i reset, I don't reconnect the serial connection.I found a way for this.I was initially expecting responses in "Serial monitor".I read in some website,that serial monitor is not suitable for 2-way communication and it suggested to used a terminal software for the same [link here](http://tronixstuff.com/2014/01/18/tutorial-arduino-mega-sm5100b-gsm-cellular/).                                     I am right now using terminal software and it is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cutting out the Arduino, for just a moment? Get yourself a UART and wire up TX/RX to the GMS respectively. Then plug it into your PC and launch terminal (Tera Term, etc.).

Try issuing some AT commands and make sure you're getting correct responses/echos. You may also want to try a tool called QNavigator (free download).